# ¿Cómo enviar un email con Nodejs a hotmail?

Tags: nodejs, express, nodemailer

He estado por un tiempo investigando como enviar un correo con nodemailer a hotmail pero no lo he conseguido.(Todos los ejemplos que me he encontrado estan para Gmail)

```
let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.live.com",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.USER_EMAIL_ACCOUNT,
      pass: process.env.USER_PASS_ACCOUNT,
    },
  });
```

Este es el código que he implementando pero aún así no me envía nada. ¿Me podrían dar una mano? De antemano les doy las gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esto ha funcionado para mi antes:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: {
       ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@hotmail.com',
        pass: 'mySuperSecurePassword'
    }
});
```

Comment: Amigo @Herberth Gomez la solución que planteas ¿debo instalar un modulo de outlook? porque me sale un error que dice : Error: Message failed: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. ¿Tienes alguna idea de que puede ser?